# Can I configure icinga to write or append on a rrd

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, icinga

I'm new to icinga and nagios. I'll appreciate any thoughts. I just like to ask, 
Can I configure icinga to write or append on a RRD file? I need to get all the historical data that icinga gets everytime. Or is there anyway for me to get all the statistics data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are already tools that can get the performance data from icinga/nagios and save in rrd format and also plot the graphs with this data.

Examples: [pnp4nagios](https://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/start) and [nagiosgraph](https://sourceforge.net/p/nagiosgraph/wiki/Home/)

Comment: I just like to know if it is okay to create my custom rrd for the services and commands that I created which the icinga doesn't have. Is there a specific template for the rrd that I will create?

Comment: If custom plug-in generates performance data along with normal output, you can generate rrd with that.

Comment: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/perfdata.html

Comment: http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/06/how-to-create-nagios-plugin-using-bash-script.html

Comment: Thanks 7171u. Exactly what I need.